# Magento deployment on multiple AWS EC2 Instances with ELB

Tags: magento-1.9, aws, deployment

What is the best way to manage multiple Magento based instances behind a load balancer? How do i manage the replication between the instances. How do i replicate the new products/images or any other changes in the code base.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is on server sync and not magento